java.io.UncheckedIOException gradle version error
When I used to create a project in react native, the 8.6 grade version would come, I would get an error again, it would be fixed when I made 8.4, now it loads as 8.8 and I get this error

What went wrong:
Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react.settings']


java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Project\AwesomeProject\android.gradle\8. 8\dependencies-accessors\569c8b261a8a714d7731d5f568e0e5c05babae10-1441a432-4169-431e-94fc-d1f227f57e44) to immutable location (C:\Proje\AwesomeProject\android. gradle\8.8\dependencies-accessors\569c8b261a8a714d7731d5f568e0e5c05babae10)

I have tried all gradle versions but I still get the same errors 8.6 8.4 gives kotlin error when I do 8.6 8.4

Resolved it for me when doing the following

Uninstalling NodeJS
Deleting the npm folder in c:\users\username\roaming\npm
Installing NodeJS
Manually creating the npm folder from above
npx @react-native-community/cli@latest init AwesomeProject

